# Is there a shorter/better way to read in browser javascript from a websocket a (binary) png image and continuously update it on the web page

Tags: javascript, websocket

With some pain (not really a javascript coder am I) I've carved following piece of code that continuously and as fast as it makes sense to display it (ie not faster than frame rate)  reads a png image binary data from a websocket and displays it on the web page where this javascript resides.

To me this seems like quite a lot of complex code for such simple task.

Do I really need the FileReader and the URL here?

And never mind the long code and complexity, is this the most efficient way to do this in javascript?

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");


socket.onmessage = function(message) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(message.data);
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(e) {
        data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);  
        myimage.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'image/png' })); 
    });

    myimage = new Image();
    myimage.onload = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(async () => {
            context.drawImage(myimage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            requestMore();
        })
    };

}
```

Comment: I think this question is better suited to Code Review on the Stack Enchange

Comment: **is this the most efficient way to do this in javascript?**   No, you might want to look into webRTC -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API

Comment: I don't quite understand: I presume `message.data` is a Blob, but why are you going from Blob to ArrayBuffer to Uint8Array to Blob? Couldn't you have converted the untyped Blob to a `type: "image/png"` Blob directly? (Since the [first parameter of the `Blob()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#blobparts) accepts an array of Blobs.)

Comment: Also don't forget to call [`URL.revokeObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL_static) after having drawn the image to prevent leaking memory

Comment: `myimage` and `data` are missing a `const` declaration, and the `requestAnimationFrame` callback shouldn't be `async`

Comment: @OskarGrosser I tried the Blob approach but that did not work for me, I may have to revisit that. I just googled and hacked until I got something that worked.

Comment: @Bergi will do thanks!

Comment: @Keith ok thanks for the tip, I will have a look.

Comment: @OskarGrosser got that bit sorted, Blob constructor expects and array of blobs (or something like that) so I need to use `new Blob([message.data], { type: "image/png" }); ` and not `new Blob(message.data, { type: "image/png" });`

Comment: @Keith I did some reading on WebRTC and it looks like there is little control over compression of data and that lossless compression is not supported which is a deal breaker here.